# Cannot switch from iPhone to iPhoneSimulator in Visual Studio 2013 for Xamarin Projects

Tags: ios, visual-studio-2012, configuration, visual-studio-2013, xamarin

There used to be an option on the toolbar in Visual Studio that allowed me to switch from iPhone (a plugged in device) to iPhoneSimulator (picking a list of simulators for iPad/iPhone).  For some reason, that dropdown is now missing.  Where did it go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, in Visual Studio 2013, for some reason they have removed Solution Platforms from the toolbar. This makes it impossible to switch from iPhone to iPhoneSimulator without opening Configuration Manager. So, to fix this do the following:

Click TOOLS/Customize then select the 'Commands' tab then select the 'Toolbar:' radio button and click the dropdown to the right of it and select 'Standard' as the toolbar you're working on.

Now, click 'Add Command' and select 'Build' from the catagories on the left and then scroll down commands until you find 'Solution Platforms'. Select that one and click OK. Then click the 'Close' button. You will now see an additional dropdown next to the Solution Configurations dropdown on your Standard Toolbar.

This will allow you to easily switch from iPhoneSimulator and iPhone. Use iPhone when you want to plug in an actual device, and use iPhoneSimulator when you want to pick a simulated device.

Hope this helps somebody out. I too have spent lots of time trying to figure this one out when I went from a device and was trying to use the simulator instead.